# SVG sprites: per-instance preserveAspectRatio

Tags: css, svg, svg-sprite

Is there any way to set the value of `preserveAspectRatio` for SVG sprites on a per-instance basis using CSS, HTML, or some other method (besides JavaScript)?

For example (none of these appear to work):

```
<!-- inline html on <svg> -->
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
  <use xlink:href="/svg/icon.svg">
</svg>
```

.

```
<!-- inline html on <use> -->
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="/svg/icon.svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
</svg>
```

.

```
<!-- inline css nested in <svg> -->
<svg>
  <style>svg { preserveAspectRatio: xMinYMin; }</style>
  <use xlink:href="/svg/icon.svg">
</svg>
```

.

```
<!-- inline css nested in <use> -->
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="/svg/icon.svg">
    <style>svg { preserveAspectRatio: xMinYMin; }</style>
  </use>
</svg>
```

.

```
<!-- head/external css -->
<style>
  .icon,
  .icon svg {
    preserveAspectRatio: xMinYMin;
  }
</style>

<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="/svg/icon.svg">
</svg>
```

Comment: <use> elements can't point to complete SVG files in most UAs currently. I can show you how to do this via an <image> element if that's any use.

Comment: @RobertLongson - thanks for responding; sure, seeing the <image> approach might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG 1.1 you can only use `<image>` elements to refer to complete files. SVG 2 relaxes this so that `<use>` elements can point to complete files but I'm not sure any UAs have implemented this.

For image elements you'd do this...

```
<svg>
  <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="/svg/icon.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none slice))">
</svg>
```

In SVG 1.1 width and height are mandatory for images. The svgView syntax is [documented here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers)

Comment: That's great to know, thanks. I'll watch for browser support.